# Finding elements with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So this is the username element of https://twitter.com/login:

```
<input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" 
name="session[username_or_email]" spellcheck="false" type="text" 
dir="auto" data-focusable="true" class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a 
r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r- 
utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu" 
value="">
```

I can find it with:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
```

but not:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj 
r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r- 
1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu")
```

Why is this the case?

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 9, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element_by_class_name("r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r- 
deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 
r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu")
  File "/home/nu7up/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/nu7up/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/nu7up/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/nu7up/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .r- 
30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 
r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r-1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu
```

The submit button element is the following:

```
<div aria-haspopup="false" role="button" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n 
r-urgr8i r-42olwf r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-vlx1xi r-zg41ew 
r-1jayybb r-17bavie r-15bsvpr r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr" data- 
testid="LoginForm_Login_Button" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0"><div 
dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r- 
16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-vw2c0b r-1777fci r-eljoum r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo 
r-q4m81j r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r- 
1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 
r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Log in</span></span></div></div>
```

How to find this element not by using its dynamic class name?

Comment: This class name is not static and thus is not a good attribute to collect. Why you need to collect if there is a clear name to select?

Comment: You mean it is not the same in my browser as when I try to reach it with selenium? I need to collect it as the submit button only has a class and no name. I will include the submit button in my edit.

Comment: It is working for both the username field and the submit button. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the class name because for some reason it's the one you need, then this is working:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path = 'PATH_TO_GECKODRIVER'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')

time.sleep(10)

x = driver.find_element_by_class_name('r-30o5oe')
x.send_keys("ole")

w = driver.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
w.send_keys("something")

y = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Log in"]')

if y.is_displayed():
    print("I see the Log in button")
    y.click()
else:
    print("I can't see it")


time.sleep(5)
```

The specific class name:

```
r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-homxoj 
r-poiln3 r-7cikom r-1ny4l3l r-1inuy60 r-utggzx r-vmopo1 r-1w50u8q r-641cr4 r-1dz5y72 r- 
1ttztb7 r-13qz1uu
```

is not a good class name since it's having dynamic values. This means that if in the future the class of this attribute will change, the whole script of yours will stop too. What you need for such cases is an attribute that is stable.

Though, As I said before, including the answer to your code and it will work as did on my case. What I did is to select only the first part of the class name because I wanted to decrease the chance of getting something that may be used by other parts of the login page too.

**Note**: Sleep parts of code are just for you to see that you can type on it with the specific class name.

Comment: I included a submit button element in my original post. How to find it without using its class name?

Comment: @smart_beaver check the new code. Now you can click on the button too. What I did is that I was trying to get the XPATH from a span element that contains a text (text()) equals to "Log in". Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Any time! If you have another problem in future ping me haha :)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS class names shouldn't contain spaces. What you are dealing with is a set of separate class names. So, if you do want to have that exact set of classes specified in your code - though it could be cumbersome - you have to make a query with the help of a CSS selector. But you have to chain classes.

Like this.

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selectors(".r-30o5oe.r-1niwhzg.r-17gur6a.r-1yadl64.r-deolkf.r-homxoj.r-poiln3.r-7cikom.r-1ny4l3l.r-1inuy60.r-utggzx.r-vmopo1.r-1w50u8q.r-641cr4.r-1dz5y72.r-1ttztb7.r-13qz1uu")`

Note that it will return more than one element.

Comment: He tried to do it with the class names and not CSS. The thing is that these dynamic elements are not safe at all. Even if they are CSS or class names because are changing often. As you already wrote these dynamic CSS or class names may also belong to many attributes in the platform. So, we may also have more than 1. Thus, these kind of selectors are like, let's say, contraband.

Comment: The initial question was "why" and not "how".

Comment: Sure, but okay from what I see 'how' was also needed in an indirect way. In any case if you think my explanation is not clear feel free to edit my answer for sure :)

Comment: I could get 2 elements by using one of these (.r-30o5oe).